# How to redirect domain with prefix www in AWS Route 53

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a problem with domain hosting in Route 53.

I need to redirect from `xyz.com` to `www.xyz.com`, so I created a Hosted Zone on Route 53. I added an A record with the address of my ELB, and a CNAME with a name of `www.xyz.com` and value of my ELB address.

But this set up does not redirect my naked domain to my `www` prefixed domain. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: This should solve your query. http://pixelcog.com/blog/2013/routing-with-s3/

Answer (score 13):

I've gotten this to work using both S3 and CloudFront.

You need two buckets: `www.yourdomainname.com` and `yourdomainname.com`.

Keep your files in the `www` bucket. For the naked domain bucket properties, go to the "Static Website Hosting" section and select "redirect all requests to another host name", and enter `www.yourdomainname.com`.

Comment: If you are like me, using a CNAME to point the www.domain.com to the host, and trying to create an Alias for the naked domain: the name of the bucket MUST BE your naked domain name (eg: domain.com). Then, create an A record, mark it as an alias and select your bucket form the dropdown. And thats it. It should work right after clicking save

Comment: Can you keep your files in the naked bucket and then redirect to www?

Comment: @netpoetica what is the point of hosting the files in naked?  If you don't like files belonging to www, you can create a cdn.domain.com.  Let the naked be its own dumb things, solely serving redirect to www.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible using only Amazon Route 53. Please have a look into [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=55995) for additional information.

Also, please be aware that a "naked domain" (e.g. `xyz.com`) redirect should be handled in the HTTP layer, not in the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps below will resolve your problem:

1. Create two buckets: one for example.com and one for www.example.com
2. Setup example.com bucket to redirect to www.example.com
3. Create two distributions: one using the example.com bucket and one using the www.example.com bucket (Use the corresponding domain for the CNAME)
4. In route 53, A ALIAS example.com to the first CloudFront distribution and A ALIAS www.example.com to the second CloudFront distribution

After the DNS changes take effect, browse to example.com and it should redirect to www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a new Load Balancer

with Listener on port 80 http that redirect 301 to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

In case you have ssl running add another listener on port 443 that redirect 301 to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

go to `Route 53`

and create a Record A with naked domain the points the new load balancer

Answer (score 0):

I just created two A records that both point the load balancer alias.

```
cstructor.com A  loadbalancer-url
www.cstructor.com A loadbalancer-url
```

Comment: When accessing cstructor.com, you will NOT get to www.cstructor.com. It points to the same load-balancer, but it's not what was asked

Comment: Correct, but this is a reasonable solution.

Comment: This worked for me. I am using it with cloud front. Thanks.