# Alias from www. on AWS Route-53 to S3 endpoint not working correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have setup two buckets on S3 one with www.mydomain.com and another with mydomain.com. All the files for my website are in the mydomain.com bucket.

On Route-53,  I have made aliases from, (as suggested by answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833039/how-to-redirect-domain-with-prefix-www-in-aws-route-53) question)

1. www.mydomain.com to S3 endpoint.
2. mydomain.com to S3 endpoint.

When I type mydomain.com, everything works fine and I see my website with mydomain.com in the URL. But using www.mydomain.com redirects to the s3 endpoint's naked URL, instead of the mydomain.com.

I also tried setting the following alias,

www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com

but that did not help either.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to setup a redirect www.mydomain.com bucket to mydomain.com bucket. Check below screenshot you need to enable that in your www.mydomain.com bucket.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! the redirect from that bucket was pointing to the naked URL earlier, but this fixed it.